# "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" - What happens next?

Tags: php

If "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" is a "warning" in PHP and doesn't halt execution, where does the script execution continue from? After the foreach block? After the function? What happens next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember it correctly, PHP runs the loop with an empty array because that is the result of the dynamic type cast from "not an array" into "array".

So basically, it will skip the loop while wasting a little bit of CPU time. Effectively nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

It continues after the foreach.